# Correct preposition with the verb "bid"

Tags: prepositions

In the context of making a proposal to someone's request on a freelance site, what is the correct preposition to use with the verb bid?

Should I say,

> I am bidding to/on/(no preposition) your request.

Does it make sense to simply say,

> I am bidding you,

even if this phrasing is somewhat informal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of an auction where you are *buying* something, you *place* a bid **on** an item.

> Example: "I bid on an eBay auction"

In the context of submitting a proposal to provide goods or services under a contract, you *make* a bid **for** the contract.

> Example: "The company made a bid for the contract to provide services".

However, when speaking about a proposal to carry out some work and you are referring to the proposed work itself rather than a contract you may gain, you *make* a bid **to** do it.

> Example: "Walmart have made a bid to build a new supermarket on the outskirts of town".